# a huge amount or huge amount

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I want to say having too much data , we need to have a good solution to proceed them. so the statement is :

> Having a huge amount of data, a huge amount of computing is needed.

now the question is : "Is it true to use 'a' with 'huge amount' or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having a huge amount of data, a huge amount of computing is needed.

Is just fine, although I would say

> Having a huge amount of data, a huge amount of **processing** is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely "a huge amount", since *amount* is countable.

That said, "a huge amount of computing" is very awkward. "Computing" is not usually viewed as something that you can have an amount of. I would suggest either "a huge amount of computing power" (if you mean that you need powerful computers, or many computers running in parallel) or "a huge amount of computation" (if you would also accept the possibility of one computer running for a very long time).